# How can I get authed to run kubectl commands in EKS when I'm not the creator of the cluster && the creator/admin isn't available?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster that's not created by me. I want to operate the cluster by running `kubectl` commands, but I keep getting `"error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)"`.

e.g.,

```
$ kubectl get pod
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

My IAM user account has `AdminFullAccess` so I believe I'm blocked by the permission of Kubernetes. According to [the AWS doc](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-api-server-unauthorized-error/?nc1=h_ls), someone who didn't create the cluster needs to ask the owner or the admin to modify `aws-auth` ConfigMap, but they already left the company. Is there any way to solve the problem?

Comment: Hello! I would start checking the kubeconfig file. kubectl expects a kubeconfig file to be available under (usually) the home directory of your user at path .kube/config. Can you check if the file is there?

Comment: Hi, yes there's a file in `$HOME/.kube/config`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is still creator's account in IAM. If so, you can [reset API-access keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html#Using_CreateAccessKey) and generate kubeconfig anew using their IAM-account. Assuming you've already configured [awscli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) for their account:

```
aws eks --region <region-code> update-kubeconfig --name <cluster_name>
```

Once you did that, you will get full access to the cluster just as the person who had left had. I recommend use this opportunity to patch `aws-auth` to enable access from your own account.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! We deleted the IAM user account of the creator, unfortunately.

Comment: @bd365 I'd rather double checked that, since AWS can prevent user account deletion if there are some resources bound to it. Just in case. If it's firmly deleted, then I'm afraid, you can only get access by luck. If there are CI/CD pipelines or some other kind of integrations, there must be credentials as well. These are normally bound to some service account and, if done well, restricted to the minimal possible permissions. However, if it was made poorly, that is why I mentioned luck, you may come to an account with permissions enough to edit the `aws-auth` or create an account that can do it.

Comment: Thanks anemyte, yeah I double-checked the list of the IAM users, and I'm very sure that the creator was deleted already. I'd say the cluster was actually made poorly, and there's no CI/CD pipeline for the cluster. Hmm.